# How to display word file in web form in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on job portal website.In that,I am having job-seeker registration form.In that job-seeker upload resume.I am saving only resume file name in database and actual resume in local folder.In another web form ,I want to show resume in div tag  just like in naukri.com's update/view profile.So how i can do this?
I can retrieve the resume file name from database.
so,please any one suggest me any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// How to: Create a new package as a Word document.
public static void CreateNewWordDocument(string document)
{
   using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(document, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
   {
      // Set the content of the document so that Word can open it.
      MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();

      SetMainDocumentContent(mainPart);
   }
}

// Set content of MainDocumentPart.
public static void SetMainDocumentContent(MainDocumentPart part)
{
   const string docXml =
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<w:document xmlns:w=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"">
    <w:body><w:p><w:r><w:t>Hello world!</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:body>
</w:document>";

    using (Stream stream = part.GetStream())
    {
       byte[] buf = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(docXml);
       stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }
}
```

Took from **[here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1905591.aspx)**

Another nice tutorial from **[here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Word-document-on-web-page-in-ASP.Net.aspx)**