# how to view a .doc file in web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i want to create a webform in asp.net and want to view a .doc file which have a path you can think that it is located in my local computer temporary.So please help me..please tell me which control is used to view .doc file.?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this tutorial its same as you required. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Word-document-on-web-page-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Your question is not well formed. The doc that is locate on your local computer can be viewed by ms world... what exactly are you try here ?

Comment: What about ms office web apps ? Are you open a solution with OWA server ?

Comment: actually i am creating a webform which need to view a .doc file if any user click a button ..at now you can assume that document is located at any path of local.so i want to know is there any control to view a .doc file in webform?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027201/how-to-display-word-file-in-web-form-in-asp-net. Please try this